# Spring-AMQP request/reply, how to manage the timeout?

Tags: rpc, spring-amqp

I am using the Spring AMQP with RabbitTemplate in request/reply mode.
I have a timeout for the reply and after this timeout I return the response to my client. The client receive the response. After that the consumer finish the treatement of the message and when he finish I receive an exception, telling that the reply is after timeout. This is good for me because I would like to make another treatment for the messages that are in timeout (publish the into another exchange), but I am not sure which is the best manner to do that.

Here some code snippets :

**RabbitTemplate :**

```
@Configuration
public class MyRabbitConfiguration extends RabbitConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public RetryRabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate() {
        CachingConnectionFactory connectionFactory = (CachingConnectionFactory) this.connectionFactory();
        connectionFactory.setPublisherReturns(true);
        Message.addWhiteListPatterns(CLASSES_TO_SEND_OVER_RABBITMQ);

        RetryRabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate = new RetryRabbitTemplate (connectionFactory);

        //use default reply to queue amq.rabbitmq.reply-to
        rabbitTemplate.setReplyTimeout(this.timeout);

        return rabbitTemplate;
    }
}
```

**RetryRabbitTemplate:**

```
public class RetryRabbitTemplate extends RabbitTemplate {


    public RetryRabbitTemplate(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
        this.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);
    }

    @Override
    public void onMessage(Message message) {
        try {
            super.onMessage(message);
        } catch (Exception e) { //catch AmqpRejectAndDontRequeueException :Reply received after timeout

            try {
                byte[] body = message.getBody();
                SerializerMessageConverter serialize = new SerializerMessageConverter();
                Object objectToSend = serialize.fromMessage(message);
                this.convertAndSend("exchange", "routing_key", objectToSend);
            } catch (Exception e1) {
                LOGGER.error("TODO");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Simple consumer with a sleep which is greater thant the sleep of my receiver so finish the treatement after the sender reply to the client:**

```
@Component
public class Consumers {

    @RabbitListener(queues = "listner.queue")
    public MyObectResponse Consumers (MyObect message) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(10000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return new MyObectResponse ();
    }
}
```

I think that this is not the best way to do, but I didn't find better solution.
Is there are someone with better idea ?
Thanks

Comment: Why do you think your solution is wrong? It looks ok to me.

Comment: Because I think that the way I make the RetryRabbitTemplate is a little bit tricky and may be there is a solution which is more elegant and right to do. I was thinking that maybe the RabbitTemplate already implement some treatement for this case and not systematically throw an exception. But I am happy if you find that it is right one.

Comment: No it doesn't, currently; I suppose we could add some kind of callback that the user supplies for replies that are received too late; feel free to open a new feature suggestion [in our JIRA](https://jira.spring.io/browse/AMQP).

Comment: Thanks, I will do tha, it will be well to have a callback function.

Comment: Note that you can also use an explicit reply queue, configured to send rejected replies to a dead-letter exchange and routed to a dead-letter queue.